# Single-ticket flights to or from Iceland that don't involve Keflavík

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, iceland

It seems like going to Iceland almost always requires an airport transfer in Reykjavík, and I'm wondering how strong that "almost" is. Does any flight exist with all of these characteristics?

- The origin/destination is any airport outside of Iceland and Greenland
- The destination/origin is any airport inside of Iceland except Keflavík
- There is not an airport transfer between Keflavík and Reykjavík City Airport
- All of the flight legs can be booked on a single ticket

Here's an example of one that meets the first three, but not the fourth: fly [from Reykjavík City to Narsarsuaq on Icelandair 131](https://www.google.com/travel/flights/s/YLv68xqKmGD7hqoq8), and then [from Narsarsuaq to Copenhagen on Air Greenland 786](https://www.google.com/travel/flights/s/oLHQNZgyhPXEzrLVA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, the vast bulk of flights from Iceland to the outside world arrive and depart from Keflavík, and most reasonable real-world itineraries are best served by one of these flights.

There are, however a few flights from [Akureyri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akureyri_Airport) scheduled to begin this June on [Niceair](https://www.niceair.is/en) to Tenerife, Copenhagen, and London, with flights to Manchester coming in the fall. There are also [limited charter flights](https://www.voigt-travel.nl/ijsland-vakantie) available from Amsterdam in the winter.

Historically, [Egilsstaðir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egilssta%C3%B0ir_Airport) has also seen limited international service, but it does not appear to have any at the moment. [Atlantic Airways](https://www.atlantic.fo/) also historically offered service to Reykjavík from Vágar in the Faroe Islands (with limited onward connections e.g. to Copenhagen available), but this service has now been moved to Keflavík.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Niceair to connect northern Iceland to London, Copenhagen and Tenerife](https://www.aviacionline.com/2022/03/niceair-to-connect-northern-iceland-to-london-copenhagen-and-tenerife/) (March 2022), Niceair will start flying between Akureyri and a few European locations:

> The company expects to start ticket sales in the next few days through its website, [www.niceair.is](http://www.niceair.is), to begin operations in June 2022.